# Verifying input to form

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to add an additional verification requirement to a form that currently works correctly.

Right now javascript checks to make sure the form has the following values before it is submitted.

1. A first name must be entered into this field.
2. A last name must be entered into this field.
3. An ID number must be entered here. The value must begin with a “V” followed by a “0” (zero) followed by seven numbers.
4. A user name must be entered into this field.

My concern is with #3. I’d like to add an additional requirement that produces a dialog message if the value of this field does not begin with a “V” followed by either a “0” or a “9” and then followed by seven numbers.

For example, these values would work:

```
V01234567
V91234567
```

These would not work:

```
V0wewewew
V11234567
```

I have tried changing:

```
if(rid.charAt(0) != 'V' || rid.charAt(1) != '0'){
```

to this

```
 if(rid.charAt(0) != 'V' || rid.charAt(1) != '0' || rid.charAt(1) != '9'){
```

but it doesn’t work.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Mike

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkrequired(which) {
 var fn = document.getElementById("fn").value;
 var ln = document.getElementById("ln").value;
 if(fn == ''){
  alert("Please enter your First Name");
  return false;
 }
 if(ln == ''){
  alert("Please enter your Last Name");
  return false;
 }
 var rid = document.getElementById("rid").value;
 var nb = rid.substring(2);
 if(rid.charAt(0) != 'V' || rid.charAt(1) != '0'){
  alert("Enter your ID correctly: V0 followed by seven numbers.");
  return false;
 }else if(nb.length != 7){
  alert("Enter your ID correctly: V0 followed by seven numbers.");
  return false;
 }else if(isNaN(nb)){
  alert("Enter your ID correctly: V0 followed by seven numbers.");
  return false;
 }
 var un = document.getElementById("un").value;
 if(un == "Enter Username" || un == ''){
  alert("Please make sure that you entered a valid username");
  return false
 }
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

 
<div id="main_content">
<FORM action="page2.html" method="POST" name=myform onSubmit="return checkrequired(this)">
<p>
 Enter your first name, last name, and Identification Number (ID) into the spaces below, and then click the Continue button. 
</p>
<p>
 1. First Name: 
 <input id="fn" type="text" name="requiredFirstName" value="" size="20" maxlength="20"> 
</p>
<p>
 2. Last Name: 
 <input id="ln" type="text" name="requiredLastName" value="" size="20" maxlength="20"> 
</p>
<p>
 3. Enter your Identification Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input id="rid" type="text" name="requiredID" placeholder="V0xxxxxxx" size="20" maxlength="20"> 
</p>
<p>
 4. Enter your Username:&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input id="un" type="text" name="requiredUsername" placeholder="Enter Username" size="15" maxlength="50"><strong>@mail.mydomain.com</strong>
</p>
<p>
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Continue"> 
</p>

</FORM>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you just use a regular expression for this? It's a perfect use-case for one.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (!/^V[09]\d{7}$/.test(rid)){
    alert("Enter your ID correctly: V0 followed by seven numbers.");
    return false;
}
```

Here's your tests:

```js
function isValid(rid) {
  return /^V[09]\d{7}$/.test(rid) ? rid + " is valid" : rid + " is invalid";
}

var array = [];

array.push(isValid("V01234567"));
array.push(isValid("V91234567"));
array.push(isValid("V0wewewew"));
array.push(isValid("V11234567"));

alert(array.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkrequired(which) {
 var fn = document.getElementById("fn").value;
 var ln = document.getElementById("ln").value;
 if(fn == ''){
  alert("Please enter your First Name");
  return false;
 }
 if(ln == ''){
  alert("Please enter your Last Name");
  return false;
 }
 var rid = document.getElementById("rid").value;
 var nb = rid.substring(2);
 if(rid.charAt(0) != 'V' || (rid.charAt(1) != '0' && rid.charAt(1) != '9')){
  alert("Enter your ID correctly: V0 followed by seven numbers.");
  return false;
 }else if(nb.length != 7){
  alert("Enter your ID correctly: V0 followed by seven numbers.");
  return false;
 }else if(isNaN(nb)){
  alert("Enter your ID correctly: V0 followed by seven numbers.");
  return false;
 }
 var un = document.getElementById("un").value;
 if(un == "Enter Username" || un == ''){
  alert("Please make sure that you entered a valid username");
  return false
 }
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

 
<div id="main_content">
<FORM action="page2.html" method="POST" name=myform onSubmit="return checkrequired(this)">
<p>
 Enter your first name, last name, and Identification Number (ID) into the spaces below, and then click the Continue button. 
</p>
<p>
 1. First Name: 
 <input id="fn" type="text" name="requiredFirstName" value="" size="20" maxlength="20"> 
</p>
<p>
 2. Last Name: 
 <input id="ln" type="text" name="requiredLastName" value="" size="20" maxlength="20"> 
</p>
<p>
 3. Enter your Identification Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input id="rid" type="text" name="requiredID" placeholder="V0xxxxxxx" size="20" maxlength="20"> 
</p>
<p>
 4. Enter your Username:&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input id="un" type="text" name="requiredUsername" placeholder="Enter Username" size="15" maxlength="50"><strong>@mail.mydomain.com</strong>
</p>
<p>
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Continue"> 
</p>

</FORM>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if(rid.charAt(0) != 'V' || rid.charAt(1) != '0')
```

to

```
if(rid.charAt(0) != 'V' ||( rid.charAt(1) != '0' && rid.charAt(1) != '9'))
```

Comment: Thank you Vikash. That's just what I'm looking for.